# Textile: using code and footnotes

Tags: redmine, textile, footnotes

Hi I'm using Redmine to write a wiki of my software. I need to put some notes next to a code section like this:

```
class.method()[1]
```

Where the "one" is a link to my note at the end of the page.
I've tried to use any method defined in the Textile syntax but it seems that it doesn't work. In fact when you use the code tag '@ @' any other tag stops working.
It's good even if I can use the link tag [[ ]] but only if it is like this [`google.com`](http://www.google.com)

Thanks for any help,

Alessandro

Comment: I've found the link-code, but nothing about the note near the code part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redmine uses [Coderay](http://coderay.rubychan.de/) to parse the code sections in the Wiki. Take a look at the documentation for the different languages. Otherwise I would suggest using comments instead of footnotes or in worst case line references to the code.

Answer (score 2):

The footnote will only work if there is an alphanumeric character directly before the opening square bracktet:

```
this[1], whereas this()[2] or this [3]

fn1. will work

fn2. won't work.

fn3. won't work.
```

At least this is true with Redmine 3.1. See this [issue](http://www.redmine.org/issues/20425) for more information.

Note that you need blank lines between `fn1.`, `fn2.` and `fn3.` to get a correct rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Redmine supports Textile markup syntax. Textile has support for footnotes. As noted on [ticket #974](http://www.redmine.org/issues/974#note-7), this is the syntax for using footnotes in Redmine:

```
    Text with a footnote[1]

    fn1. and here the actual footnote.
```

Answer (score 0):

This [extension](http://www.r-labs.org/projects/r-labs/wiki/Wiki_Extensions_en) for Redmine supports footnotes and custom styles in the wiki.